# How to use Oracle Triggers in SQLAchemy

Tags: python, oracle, triggers, sqlalchemy

I have defined my data model using ORM in SQLAlchemy. I wish all my tables to include three columns

1. `created_at`
2. `last_updated`
3. `updated_by`

The data model will be deployed in a Oracle Database Schema. I could do something like

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, DateTime, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import as_declarative

@as_declarative(bind=engine)
class Base(object):

    created_at = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now(), nullable=False)
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now(), nullable=False)
    updated_by = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

**BUT** then the database default timezone is not being used AND users have to manually identify themselves when inserting/altering data. The data can be manipulated as well.

I'd much rather use a trigger which I know is possible in Oracle but how do I implement this in SQLAlchemy? I strongly prefer to define the whole data model design within SQLAlchemy if possible.

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7888846/146325)

Comment: I have seen that already, but that isn't sufficient to solve my problem. Need more specific guidance at least

Comment: The SQLAlchemy part was in the dupe linked by @APC. The rest is Oracle specific. Btw your defaults are wrong: you set them to a fixed datetime by calling the `datetime.now()` then and there. You should be passing the function itself, i.e. `default=datetime.now`. You could also use an SQL function expression that has the correct timezone as default, if you need to. Something along the lines of `default=func.now()`, plus what you might need.