# SQLAlchemy subqueries prohibited in CHECK constraints workaround

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a database using Declarative Mapping with 2 tables where one table needs to check if a column of the other table has a specific value at least one time in it. I can not use a foreign key constraint because the value is not unique.

```
class Table_A(DeclarativeBase):
    classification_a = Column(String)
    classification_b = Column(String)
    value= Column(REAL)
    ...

class Table_B(DeclarativeBase):
    name= Column(String)
    classification = Column(String)  # must be in Table_A.classification_a 
    value= Column(REAL)
    ...
```

**Example Table A**

```
classification_a     classification_b     value
a                    a                    5 
a                    b                    8
a                    c                    0
b                    a                    1
b                    b                    6
b                    c                    8
c                    a                    9
c                    b                    7
c                    c                    9
```

**What I want:**

When I insert into `Table_B` with `classification` equal to a,b or c -> insert a new row into the database.

All other values for `classification` should raise an error.

**What I tried:**

I tried to use a CheckConstraint in `Table_B` which would exactly achieve what I want like the following code:

```
CheckConstraint("classification  IN (SELECT classification_a FROM Table_A)")
```

this leads to `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) subqueries prohibited in CHECK constraints` because sqlite3 do not support subqueries in Checks.

---

On this question it was suggested to use a `@validates` decorator but I do not know how I should check the other table columns in this method because I do not have access to a session within the method with the decorator.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7890829/10685

**Question:**

How can I get my "Constraint" implemented in the `Table_B` Class?

**Software:**

Python 3.6.4

SQLAlchemy 1.2.7

sqlite version: 3.15.2

Comment: what about deleting a records from `Table_A`? Can the data be deleted?

Comment: @Danila Ganchar Why should I delete data from Table_A? I do not know if it is possible to delete data from different tables in the DeclarativeBase class. After the insert in Table_B I need the same content in Table_A as before the insert in Table_B.