# Regenerate SQLalchemy Sequence on update

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, sequence

Imagine I have a class in my models like this:

```
class Sample(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sample'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = Column(String(50))
    lastname = Column(String(50))
    auto_generated_code = Column(
        Integer, 
        Sequence('sample_auto_generated_code_sequence'),
        unique=True
    )
```

When I add an instance to `Sample` class, after flushing the session, my instance get an integer number automatically. so far so good.

What I also want is, when I update any of other columns of the mentioned instance, it should get a new `auto_generated_code` automatically. 
In simple word I want my `Sequence` to generate another code on `update` too. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the `auto_generated_code` to execute even when you are trying to update? If so, triggers and sqlalchemy events should be of help.

Comment: @JRajan. yes I want exactly that. In sqlalchemy events, How can I say to my sequence to generate new ?

Comment: You can use triggers to do the update. Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7890829/690576

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer that we can get the Sequence object in Sqlalchemy like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import Sequence

seq = Sequence('sample_auto_generated_code_sequence')
```

Then we can get the next Sequence by executing it on our connection or session

```
instance.auto_generated_code = session.execute(seq) # or conn.execute(seq)
```

Then by adding it to the session it will go just fine.