# sqlalchemy create a column that is autoupdated depending on other columns

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to create a column in a table that is autoupdated if one or more columns (possibly in another table) are updated, but it also should be possible to edit this column directly (and value should be kept in sql unless said other cols are updated, in which case first logic is applied)

I tried column_property but it seems that its merely a construction inside python and doesnt represent an actual column

I also tried hybrid_property and default, both didnt accomplish this

This looks like insert/update trigger, however i want to know "elegant" way to declare it if its even possible

I use declarative style for tables on postgres

I dont make any updates to sql outside of sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0):

Definitely looks like insert/update triggers. But if I were you, I would incapsulate this logic in python by using 2 queries , so it will be more clear

Comment: I definitely can, but i was looking for a more simple out of the box solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888846/trigger-in-sqlachemy
this seems to be it, but not sure if it can update other fields, solution with DDL expressions seems very dirty

Comment: Im probably going for the method im using to modify tables (its the only one) instead of triggers and whatnot, if someone has a better suggestion please share it