# How to create an internally computed filed in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using the ORM from SqlAlchemy. I have an Table that needs to set an field by conditions. The field must(!) be stored in the database.

In my example the field 'dyn_label' should be set in condition by the id:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///test.sqlite3', echo=False, hide_parameters=True)
Base = declarative_base()
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)


class Test(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'test'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    dyn_label = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Test(id='%s', dyn_label='%s')>" \
               % (self.id, self.dyn_label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    session = Session()

    test1 = Test()
    test2 = Test()
    session.add(test1)
    session.add(test2)
    print(test1)
    print(test2)
    session.commit()
    print(test1)
    print(test2)
```

Output:

```
<Test(id='None', dyn_label='None')>
<Test(id='None', dyn_label='None')>
<Test(id='1', dyn_label='None')>
<Test(id='2', dyn_label='None')>
```

wanted Output:

```
<Test(id='None', dyn_label='I have no ID')>
<Test(id='None', dyn_label='I have no ID')>
<Test(id='1', dyn_label='My id is 1')>
<Test(id='2', dyn_label='My id is 1')>
```

Edit:

I know that there are database triggers, I could use, but I like to know the way you can do it in SqlAlchemy. Well, I also want to stay in pure python code, while I am developing and the code should work with any db ... ini my case sqlite3 and postgresql.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger in sqlachemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888846/trigger-in-sqlachemy)

Comment: Hi, not really. Normally I would use a trigger on the pg-server, but I like to know how it can work in sqlalchemy. While developing I use sqlite3 anyways.

Comment: See the accepted answer in the duplicate. It contains an example how to to it at ORM level!

Comment: See the `@validates` part in the answer linked by rfortekaas

Comment: ok, sorry, I did not see that. The solution is working, but not for the id (pkey). I think, cause it is not set directly.